# React-native + redux application not reacting to prop changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using `React-Native` with the `react-redux` library and I've run into a problem where my interfaces aren't updating when receiving new props while not at the top of the `<Navigator>`. This is typcailly fine, however the problem is when I pop back to a component that has new props due to changes in the current component, they're not updated until I leave the page and come back, forcing a re-render. An example of this can be seen below.

```
<MessageList
    messages={this.props.threads}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    onItemPressed={() => this.navigation.goto('Messenger')} />

<Messenger
    messages={this.props.messages}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    onExit={this.navigation.pop} />
```

When a message is sent from `<Messenger>` it will update the props used by `<MessageList>` for displaying the last message sent. However, because `<MessageList>` wasn't the active component, it didn't react to the prop changes.

I should add that I'm relying on `componentWillReceiveProps` in the `<MessageList>` in order to generate a `DataSource` for the underlying `<ListView>` that is used. How can I counter this behavior. I don't want to just keep pushing new components onto the Navigation stack, as that gets messy really quickly and I can't keep a programmatical map of the navigation flow.

Comment: Can you add some more code?
Your reducer where you add messages, for example.

Comment: @stinodes A simple array reducer that uses `slice()` to copy the array, mutates the copy and returns it as the new state.